# Facing issue with DXA publish navigation page

Tags: sdl-tridion

Publishing of Navigation Page in DXA Publication throws the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I previewed a Navigation configuration Component I get the following details:

> <tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040356" Category="18" Source="Kernel"
> xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line
> ErrorCode="80040356" Cause="true"></tcm:Line></tcm:Error>

Page publish was working before, not sure what change made this happen. There is no metadata configured for that Publication.

here is a stack trace:-

> at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
> engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)    at
> Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
> __engine, Package __package)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)   
> at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)   
> at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
> template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
> template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderContext context)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject
> item, Template template, PublishInstruction instruction,
> PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.RenderComponentPresentationAsRenderedItem(TcmUri
> componentUri, TcmUri componentTemplateUri)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.RenderComponentPresentation(TcmUri
> componentUri, TcmUri componentTemplateUri)    at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.RenderComponentPresentations.Transform(Engine
> engine, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
> engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)    at
> Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
> __engine, Package __package)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)   
> at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package) Event Xml:100200x8000000000000015667123Tridiondummy.comObject reference not set to an instance of
> an object.

Comment: Did you try running this page in TemplateBuilder using debug mode?
this should give more info

Comment: you should check logs in event viewer of the publisher. It normally has a full stack trace. This is a classic null pointer exception so you need stack trace to see what is being null in rendering

Comment: Hi @shahid and marko i just edited my question and attached stack trace.

Comment: ok so it means your code is trying to read metadata. please check in code where are you reading it. since metadata is not mandatory, you need to check if it is not null before reading it.

Comment: Hi @marko we have already checked this point but no luck.

Comment: @Naveet: In your error, it shows Xml:100200x8000000000000015667123Tridiondummy.com? what was that component or template?